# Update label of UITableViewCell on the event of UIbutton click using sender tag

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

In my application i'm creating dynamic UILabel and UIButton dynamically in UITableviewCell. And their tags are UITableviewCell indexPath.row. I want to update UILabel on the click event of UIButton which have same tag of UIButton.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UIGridViewRow";
    MyCustomCell *Cell  = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
         btnHeart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         [btnHeart setFrame:CGRectMake(150,350,20,20)];
         [btnHeart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [btnHeart addTarget:self action:@selector(HeartPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
         btnHeart.tag = indexPath.row;
         [cell addSubview:btnHeart];

         lblHeart = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(175, 350, 20, 20)];
         [lblHeart setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [lblHeart setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
         [lblHeart setTag:indexPath.row];
         [lblHeart setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[appdel.PhotoAry objectAtIndex:photo.tag] valueForKey:@"Hearts"]]];
         [cell addSubview:lblHeart];
    }
}

-(IBAction)HeartPressed:(id)sender
{
     urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://zealousys.com/PeekaBoo_Webservice/heart.php?uid=%@&pid=%@",appdel.strUserid,[[appdel.PhotoAry objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] valueForKey:@"ImageID"]];

     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
     NSError *myError = nil;
     NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
     lblHeart.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[res valueForKey:@"Hearts"]];
}
```

Here I want to update lblHeart which has same tag as btnHeart tag in HeartPressed event of UITableviewCell.

Comment: after setting new title to your lable you need to call [yourTableview reloadData];

Comment: Here I don't want to reload whole tableview, i just want to update particular cell label on button event.

Comment: your code is messy you've added label to self.view and added that code in tableviewcell method??

Comment: sorry actually there is cell but self.view written by me by mistake.

Comment: okay so tell me one thing how can you update the label of only one cell? which is a part of a table? i don't think it's possible without reloading tabledata so must have to reload table after updating text of your label

Comment: Actullay i get the table data from web service. And on the click of Heart button it increments the heart count by 1 using another web service. so i dont want to reload tableview because it's take too much time for reloading because there is too much data. Just i want to update particular heart label of cell which value i'm already get  in web service response of heart update.

Comment: You should name your object 'cell' instead of 'Cell' and 'heartPressed:' instead of 'HeartPressed:'. The static string is fine. And also, I think you should add the button and label to cell.contentview instead of cell. Also, don't forget to return the UITableViewCell in `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 5):

You need to get The UITableViewCell at click index and after that you can update the label  out there inside the UITableViewCell

```
NSIndexPath *likedIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:likedIndex];

          for (UIView *subView in cell.subviews) {

              if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

                    //sender.tag = button tag
                  if (subView.tag == sender.tag) {

                      [(UILabel *) subView setText:@"Hearts"];
                  }
              }
          }
```

Hope it may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast sender to the specific class and read tag.

```
 UIButton* buttonClicked = (UIButton*) sender;
 lblHeart.tag = buttonClicked.tag;
```

Comment: But how can i set text of lblHeart which have the tag same as Uibutton

Answer (score 0):

Although GyanendraSingh's answer is partially good, you should cast the `UITableViewCell`.

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:likedIndex];
```

Also, it might be better to create properties in `MyCustomCell`. If you do that you're code can look like this:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]];

cell.lblHeart.text = @"Hearts";
```

Just did this last morning. You don't have to call `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add your `Label` to that `UIButton's` `accessibilityCustomActions` array:

```
btnHeart.accessibilityCustomActions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: lblHeart];
```

Then get this control from the sender by typecasting it:

```
- (void)btnHeart_click:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btnHeart = (UIButton *)sender;
    DBG(@"%li", btnHeart.tag);
    NSArray *arrHeart = (NSArray *)btnHeart.accessibilityCustomActions;
    UILabel *lblHeart = (UILabel *)[arrHeart objectAtIndex:0]; // getting 0th index of `accessibilityCustomActions` array.

    lblHeart.text = @"500";
}
```

That way you will get the `UILabel` you want but it will not show updated text until you will change text value inside your `appdel.PhotoAry's` that particular index's `NSDictionary`